# Can heroku support more than one language

Tags: heroku

Would heroku support if my application has three web services out of which two of them are Java and third one is node.js?

Can we deploy more than one WAR in Heroku application?

Kindly let me know the details of deploying it over heroku.

Comment: For more on Heroku philosophy, see [The Twelve-Factor App](http://www.12factor.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's kind of contrary to Heroku's design philosophy, which tends to separate out services between dynos.  It would be ideal to use two or three Heroku apps to serve your application, separated by language or by web service.

From a technical standpoint, you can't do it with the default Heroku web dyno environment, since different software is loaded onto the dyno depending on whether the application is Java or node.js.  An application that is detected as being java will not have the requisite binaries and libraries for node.js and vice versa.

However, there's technically nothing stopping you from crafting your own [Heroku buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) which includes all necessary software to run both Java and node.js simultaneously.  You can take a look at Heroku's github account to see how they did their Java and their node.js buildpacks and merge the software somehow.  This is a big project, since you'll have to use the Heroku buildpack build environment via Vulcan and dissect the build and app detection scripts for both buildpacks to merge them.  But, there's no actual rule against it and there's no technical reason why you couldn't get it to work eventually.

Comment: You don't need several Heroku accounts, but it would be appropriate to use more than one Heroku app. You can point them to the same services via configuration variables so they function together, but each component should be a separate repository in a separate Heroku application.

Comment: Yes, I misspoke. You can put as many Heroku apps on an account as you wish.  I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for the responses @AndrewGorcester and willglynn , it helped in understanding basics of heroku philosophy. IF i have 3 java services running in my application and a wordpress blog, would heroku be best option for me? or shall i look into other polygat paas like cloudfoundry

Comment: Depends on your performance needs and how much money you're willing to spend.  To save money you could probably serve all three java services from the same app.  Wordpress should be served separately.  Also: if you want to use Wordpress on Heroku, do not use the default PHP buildpack.  It is terrible.  Maybe try forking [my buildpack](https://github.com/andrewsg/heroku-buildpack-php-winglian) (only slightly tuned from the excellent winglian buildpack) which I'm using in production for Wordpress right now.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGorcester. ok, if i have three services in my java application, then i can run them as three web processes in same app. In above answer, you suggested to use different app even if i have more than one service in same language, any specific reason for that? I can run these services in same app and increase number of dyno's. would love to hear more on this from you. Thanks

Comment: One reason is that if one app suffers extreme load, it may disable your other apps if it goes down; another is that if you push code changes to one app, all of the other apps will be taken down along with the dyno.  It also makes sense to store your apps in separate repositories for each app, but you can only load one git reference to a dyno at a time.  However, the cost savings are potentially significant.  Think about how tightly coupled your apps are and how much sense it makes to bind their operation together by running them on the same nodes.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Lets say if redis is running as addon to one of my app. Can i access the same addon from my another app? and how efficient would that be? In that case, shall i consider running them on same nodes?Also, Would appreciate if you could elaborate more on how cost savings can be significant in above case? Didn't get that.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was "As a counterpoint to the arguments I presented for running them all on separate apps, the cost savings of NOT doing so are significant" -- you'll probably save money with fewer apps unless your overall load is pretty high.  As for an addon: Yes, you can share them between apps.  Just use `heroku config` to view the parameters for accessing your app that are automatically added to the app you purchased the addon for, and add that to your other apps with `heroku config:add`.  At least, this has been true for all of the addons I personally have used so far.

Comment: The Wordpress buildpack I reference above has been renamed to https://github.com/andrewsg/heroku-buildpack-php-foundry to avoid confusion.  The old link will no longer work, so if you're using it, please use this new one!